# Pass (i+1) th data in (i)th anchor click in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Can I pass i+1 data while clicking on i th anchor in angular2 using ngFor.

Can anyone pls help me

```
   <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let menu of _menus;let k=index" >
            <a (click)="GoToSectionPage()">{{menu.Title}}</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

I used above code for binding array of data.can i pass k+1 th data in GoToSectionPage() method.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the index like this :

```
(click)="GoToSectionPage(k)"
```

In your component use following code:

```
public GoToSectionPage(k: number) {
  const menu = this._menus[k+1];
  //some code will be here according to your need
}
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. Just pass it as parameter to the function

```
(click)="GoToSectionPage(k+1)"
```

In the component class access the parameter.

```
GoToSectionPage(key: any) {
   console.log(this._menus[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,But it will pass index only(k=1 means 2).I am asking for data.means 2nd data

Comment: @kamalav you can get the value from the index. check the updated answer.